# NULLs and SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bit of SQL that queries a table that has one column that can take `NULL`.
In the code below the `@term_type_id` could be `NULL`, and the column `term_type_id` could have `NULL` values.
So the code below works if `@term_type_id` has a value, but does not work if `@term_type_id` is `NULL`.
Setting `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` is a way around the problem, but I do know that this will be depreciated at some stage.

```
SELECT      [date],value FROM history 
WHERE       id=@id 
AND         data_type_id=@data_type_id
AND         quote_type_id=@quote_type_id 
AND         update_type_id=@update_type_id
AND         term_type_id=@term_type_id
AND         source_id=@source_id
AND         ([date]>=@temp_from_date and [date]<=@temp_to_date)
ORDER BY    [date]
```

What I have done in the past is to have something like this

```
if @term_type_id is NULL 
BEGIN
    SELECT ......
    WHERE .....
    AND term_type_id IS NULL
END
BEGIN
    SELECT ......
    WHERE .....
    AND term_type_id = @term_type_id
END
```

While this works, it is very verbose and makes the code hard to read and maintain.
Does anyone have a better solution than using `SET ANSI_NULLS` OFF or having to write conditional code just to manage the case when something could be a value or `NULL`?

BTW - When I use SET ANSI_NULLS OFF, I only do it for the specific query then turn it back on afterwards. I do understand the reasons why this is frowned upon, but it is at the expense of writing pointless code to get around a 'pure' view of NULL.

Ben

Comment: One way is to use`WHERE (id = @id OR @id IS NULL) AND (data_type_id=@data_type_id OR @data_typeId IS NULL) ... ` **[The “Kitchen Sink”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0A-QyzaRuk)**

Answer (score 1):

Since both the column and the parameter can be null, you should treat both cases:

```
SELECT      [date],value FROM history 
WHERE       id=@id 
AND         data_type_id=@data_type_id
AND         quote_type_id=@quote_type_id 
AND         update_type_id=@update_type_id
AND         ((term_type_id IS NULL AND @term_type_id IS NULL) OR term_type_id = @term_type_id)
AND         source_id=@source_id
AND         ([date]>=@temp_from_date and [date]<=@temp_to_date)
ORDER BY    [date]
```

Note that this will only return results when both column and parameter are null, or none of them is null.

Answer (score 1):

Ben, a better solution to `if @term_type_id is NULL SELECT @term_type_id=-1`
would be to use `isnull(@term_type_id,-1)`

Comment: Cameron - yes it would indeed. Makes it much cleaner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work on both case.

```
SELECT ......
WHERE .....
    AND ISNULL(term_type_id,-1) = ISNULL(@term_type_id,-1)
```

You can use any static value instead of `-1`

Or you can use something like below

```
SELECT ......
WHERE .....
    AND (   (@term_type_id IS NULL AND term_type_id IS NULL) 
            OR term_type_id = @term_type_id 
        )
```

Comment: This won't work if @term_type_id is null and term_type_id is set

Comment: Why, if @term_type_id is set to NULL , then it will return all the records even if the column  term_type_id is value, bcs and using OR here)

Comment: The OP's "What I have done in the past is to have something like this" query will only select rows where `term_type_id` is null when `@term_type_id` is set to null. Your query will select everything when `@term_type_id` is null

Comment: OK thnx , modified the query, will return only matched records now, as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh - yes - thank you for the prompt responses. I think I have just come up with a better solution (well in this case)...

```
if @term_type_id is NULL SELECT @term_type_id=-1

SELECT      [date],value FROM   history 
WHERE       id=@id 
AND         data_type_id=@data_type_id
AND         quote_type_id=@quote_type_id 
AND         update_type_id=@update_type_id
AND         ISNULL(term_type_id,-1)=@term_type_id
AND         source_id=@source_id
AND         ([date]>=@temp_from_date and [date]<=@temp_to_date)
ORDER BY    [date]
```

This works in this case as term_type_id is the result of an identity (1,1) and thus can not be -1.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that applying functions such as `isnull` on columns in the where clause prevents sql server query optimizer from using any indexes that might be otherwise used with this column. Having said that, if you are going with `isnull` on the column you might as well do it on the parameter also: `ISNULL(term_type_id,-1) = ISNULL(@term_type_id, -1)` and get rid of that `if` on the top.

Comment: Thank you Zohar - good point.  I will check the performance and see if this is an issue

Answer (score 0):

If it's the only nullable column among your search criteria, the best way would be to split conditions within a single `UNION` statement:

```
select date, value from dbo.History
where term_type_id is null
  -- Remaining search criteria
  and ...
union all
select date, value from dbo.History
where term_type_id = @term_type_id
  -- Remaining search criteria
  and ...
```

This is the fastest code possible in your case, basically because SQL Server doesn't have a particular knack for `OR`-ed conditions. However, another nullable column will turn this into a rather unpleasant mess.

If you think you can sacrifice performance, there is a useful function in T-SQL that does exactly that - `NULLIF()`:

```
select date, value from dbo.History
where nullif(@term_type_id, term_type_id) is null
  -- Remaining search criteria
  and ...
```

However, this type of condition will be non-SARGable, most likely. Also, note that the order of arguments does matter in `NULLIF()`. Alternatively, you can devise `CASE` constructs of various complexity that might be semantically more suitable to your exact requirements.